# How to create an in instance using HyperlinkedModelSerializer by just providing the url of the nested HyperlinkedModelSerializer fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an instance of a model which has all its fields to be the related fields.

```
class LearnerQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz_question = models.ForeignKey(Quiz_Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    learner = models.ForeignKey(Learner_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chosen_option = models.ForeignKey(Answer_Options, related_name="chosen_option", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

For this model I have created the following serializer:-

```
class LearnerQuestionAnswerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    quiz_question = Quiz_QuestionSerializer()
    learner = Learner_ModelSerializer()
    chosen_option = Answer_OptionsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = LearnerQuestionAnswer
        fields = ('quiz_question', 'learner', 'chosen_option')
```

All the nested serializer's are as well HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

I want to create an instance of this model by just providing the urls of the related fields like for example consider the following POST method:-

```
{
    "quiz_question":  "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/83/",
    "learner":  "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_learners/3/",
    "chosen_option": "http://localhost:8080/api/registration_answer_options/218/",
}
```

Is this possible an how?

Comment: Suppose, your `Quiz_Question` model contains `n` number of fields then, how could you populate those `n` fields with just one url, `http://localhost:8080/api/registration_quiz_questions/83/` ?

Comment: also, the `id`/`pk` seems like auto-generated. So, it would be defficult to achieve exacly as per your requirements

Comment: I don't want to create new fields. I just want to reference the instances of the existing models. 83 is the id of the existing quiz question which I just want to be referenced similarly I want to just reference the learner field and chosen_option field through id without creating new instances of those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HyperlinkedModelSerializer`using for related fields `HyperlinkedRelatedField` by default, which can give you desired behavior. To represent data as nested objects you can override `to_representation` method:

```
class LearnerQuestionAnswerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LearnerQuestionAnswer
        fields = ('quiz_question', 'learner', 'chosen_option')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['quiz_question'] = Quiz_QuestionSerializer()
        self.fields['learner'] = Learner_ModelSerializer()
        self.fields['chosen_option'] = Answer_OptionsSerializer()
        return super(LearnerQuestionAnswerSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

Comment: I tried POST method, but it's giving me error :-  "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 5 column 1 (char 242)". My POST request is same as in the question did i miss something?

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Tried removing one space as well as tried with no space. But the same error persists.

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis ahh, remove comma after last line.